# Meteor: Sharing a template variable between templates

Tags: templates, meteor

I am building a UI, that gives users the ability to filter results based on a filter field that they are currently using. Currently this is all in one single ui and structured like this:

```
Template.clientList.onCreated(function(){
  var instance = this;

  // filterDictionary manages the filter parameters. 
 instance.filterDictionary = new ReactiveDict();
 instance.filterDictionary.set("filterName", null);
 instance.filterDictionary.set("filterDate", null);
 instance.filterDictionary.set("filterId", null);

 // subscription management goes here, uses filterDictionary. 

});
```

I now want to reuse the filter in another template and would like to embed it in a child template. So this should change to something like this:

```
Template.filterTemplate.onCreated(function(){
  var instance = this;
  instance.filterDictionary = instance.canIAccessChildTemplates.filterDictionary;

 // subscription management goes here, uses filterDictionary.
 // subscriptions will also use parameters specific to the template they are in.
});
```

What is the best way to access data between children? I really don't want this to be a global variable as it's conceivable you may want these two ui elements next to each other, ie display 2 views at the same time and they must not apply their changes to the same ReactiveDict.

Comment: You can share the variable using [`Session`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session).

Comment: I specifically do not want to use the `Session`, as I may be reusing this template in various places and the Session would be global. Setting this as per below answer by Curtis works really well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are embedding `filterTemplate` inside the `clientList` template you can pass data like:

```
{{> filterTemplate filterDictionary=filterDictionary}}
```

Where `filterDictionary` is a template helper for `clientList`. If it is not embedded inside the other template you will have to use `Session` variables.